# Removing padding from TextView and ImageButton

Tags: android, padding

My first question here, but not new, as I've been reading a lot...
I'm developing an small android app using Android Studio.
Everything is working fine except a major annoyance while designing the interface using TextView and ImageButton.
It seems that there's a padding on each control, on left and top side. I don't know how to remove it.
It causes the elements to not be centred on the screen.

This is what I mean:

[image]

This is the code of the button:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/resultLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/partialLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/periodDownButton"
                android:onClick="onClickPeriodDown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/previous" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/periodDown"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentPeriodTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/empty1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners" android:textSize="30sp" android:textColor="#FFFFF000" android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center" android:padding="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:width="40dp" android:minWidth="40dp" android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/periodUpButton"
                android:onClick="onClickPeriodUp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/next" android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/periodUp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/visitorPartialTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/borde3"
                android:text="@string/empty2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFF000"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:padding="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a default padding somewhere?
Is padding inherited?

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your full code of XML...

Comment: At a first glance i would the button image is not centered , but it's probably not the case. It would help to see the full XML code

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY"  put this in ImageView Tag

Comment: Added full code. Just to say that tested on a device, give same result as in AS preview.

Answer (score 2):

Set the value of `android:scaleType` attribute to `fitXY` as below and add the attribute to your `ImageButton`.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

So, updated `ImageButton` XML will be

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/periodDownButton"
    android:onClick="onClickPeriodDown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/previous" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/periodDown"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: It did nothing. It doesn't affect to the button.

Answer (score 0):

try below code;-

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/periodDownButton"
android:onClick="onClickPeriodDown"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
nadroid:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/previous" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/periodDown"/>
```

add one more line

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: Just reduces the size of the button to the size of the icon. The grey background is not part of the drawable. Only the green circle with the arrow.